# let vs member for private functions, in F#

Tags: f#

Let's consider this code:

```
type TransactionTypes =
| TransactionType1
| TransactionType2

type Test() =

    let mutable lastTransactionType1 = DateTime.MinValue
    let mutable lastTransactionType2 = DateTime.MinValue

    let getLastTransaction transaction =
        match transaction with
        | TransactionType1 -> lastTransactionType1
        | TransactionType2 -> lastTransactionType2

    let updateLastTransaction transaction =
        match transaction with
        | TransactionType1 -> lastTransactionType1 <- DateTime.UtcNow
        | TransactionType2 -> lastTransactionType2 <- DateTime.UtcNow
```

Now (with the understanding that I'm still learning F#), I would like to clarify a couple things:

Something like:

```
let a = DateTime.Now
```

does a permanent binding, so 'a' will always be the same time on subsequent uses.

But, my understanding is that if there is a parameter, like:

```
let a anyParameter = DateTime.Now
```

will be re-evaluated every time due to the presence of the parameter. Is that correct?

In the code above, the two let statements (getLastTransaction and updateLastTransaction) are private to the type (Test)

I could also have implemented them as:

```
member private this.getLastTransaction = ...
member private this.updateLastTransaction = ...
```

Is there any reason, for private functions to prefer let vs. member private this?
"let mutable" already implies the this. so the fields are accessible by both forms.

So, what is the advantage of one form vs. the other?

Comment: how would it answer the advantage of one form vs. the other? The reason I ask these questions is because between let, member and val, the mapping to fields/methods/properties is a bit blurry and why there are already discussions about the subject, I can't find an answer to the question I wrote

Comment: I can write let x _ = do something, or member this.x = do something, or member this.x() = do something... there has to be some differences in practice. I guess I can always implement a method as a property, so member this.x = maybe not the best, but that leaves my question: member this vs. let in a private situation.. what's the real difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Tomas' answer:

```
  let mutable lastTransactionType1 = DateTime.MinValue
```

is equivalent in C# to:

```
internal DateTime lastTransactionType1 = DateTime.MinValue;
```

and

```
member private this.getLastTransaction ...
```

is the same IL as far as IL is concerned with

```
let getLastTransaction ...
```

In equivalent C#, both are

```
internal DateTime getLastTransactionMember(TransactionTypes transaction)
{
    if (transaction.Tag != 1)
    {
        return lastTransactionType1;
    }
    return lastTransactionType2;
}
```

But for using F# in an idiomatic way, you would want to go with  `let`. 
There's also a difference in that `member` does let you use the methods in bindings *before* their declaration, which might be useful in some cases (read: hacks)

```
let getType1 = this.getLastTransactionMember TransactionType1 //this compiles

member private this.getLastTransactionMember transaction =
        match transaction with
        | TransactionType1 -> lastTransactionType1
        | TransactionType2 -> lastTransactionType2
```

Comment: this brings up an additional question: let foo x = ... is evaluated everything, let foo = 3 is not, but what about the cases where you have let foo = doSomethingThatDoesn'tReturnAnything, will the doSomething... be evaluated every time? for example let ClearCache = myCache.ClearItNow

Comment: No, just once when the type is constructed. It's similar to a readonly field in C#. Called every time would be a function `() -> T`; i.e., let ClearCache () = myCache.ClearItNow ()

Comment: ok, thanks; I have to wrap my mind around the fact that the presence or absence of parameters changes the meaning of let :) It may be safer for me, at the beginning, to use let strictly for binding and member this.foo() for method :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with members, F# inherits a lot of things from the .NET object model. A .NET object can have a couple of different things:

- Fields - those are storing a value (just like fields of a record). They can be mutable or immutable.
- Methods - those can be invoked with zero or more arguments (like functions)
- Properties - those have no arguments (like fields); they can be read or written, but when this happens, some code is invoked. A property is basically a pair of getter and setter methods.

In F#, some of this is less visible. However, `let` corresponds to a field and `member` with arguments corresponds to a method. Your tricky case is a member without arguments. For example:

```
type A() = 
  member x.Foo = printfn "Hi"; 42
```

Will `Hi` be printed only once, or will it be printed each time you access `Foo`? To answer, it's useful to know that `Foo` is a property with a getter. The above is actually a syntactic sugar for the full version:

```
type A() = 
  member x.Foo 
    with get() = printfn "Hi"; 42
```

Now you can see that there is a method behind the `Foo` property! Each time you access `Foo`, the compiler will generate a call to the `get()` method, so `Hi` will be printed repeatedly.

Comment: so: let=field, member x.Foo with or without arguments = method or property? right? but what about let Foo x = ? in this case it is also a method, not a field

Comment: `let Foo x = ...` is an F# function and will be compiled as a method

Comment: so, is there any practical difference between let foo x = ... and member private this.foo x = ... ? is one more recommended, for any reason?

Comment: @Thomas There's very little practical difference between the two - if you use a member, you have access to the `this` instance (which you don't with `let`). This makes `let` a bit easier to compile (the compiler does not need to do some checks that it would do for members). But aside from this, they're the same. My preference is to use `let`, simply because it's more lightweight.